# Applying schema at message level instead of dataframe level in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

So, the thing is since my schema could depend on kafka header/key, I want to apply schema at message level rather then dataframe level. How to achieve this? Thanks

The code snippet to apply schema for dataframe level is:

```
val ParsedDataFrame = kafkaStreamData.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(key AS STRING)")
  .select(from_json(col("value"), Schema), col("key"))
  .select("value.*","key")
```

I want something like,

```
if(key == 'a'){
   use Schema1
}
else{
   use Schema2
}
```

P.S: I tried using foreach and map function but none worked, maybe not using them correctly

Comment: You'd have to separate out messages into separate dataframes first using a filter. There's no concept of a schema per row

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to apply a different schema in the same row as you would end up getting an `AnalysisException` due to data type mismatch.

To test this you can do the following experiment.

Have the following data in Kafka topic in the forma `key:::value`:

```
a:::{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}
b:::{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}
```

In your streaming query you define:

```scala
val schemaA = new StructType().add("a", StringType)
val schemaB = new StructType().add("b", StringType)

val df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .[...]
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .withColumn("parsedJson", 
    when(col("key") === "a", from_json(col("value"), schemaA))
    .otherwise(from_json(col("value"), schemaB)))
```

This will result in an `AnalysisException`:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (`key` = 'a') THEN jsontostructs(`value`) ELSE jsontostructs(`value`) END' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;
'Project [key#21, value#22, CASE WHEN (key#21 = a) THEN jsontostructs(StructField(a,StringType,true), value#22) ELSE jsontostructs(StructField(b,StringType,true), value#22) END AS parsedJson#27]
```

As @OneCricketeer mentioned in the comments, you need to seperate the kafka input stream into several Dataframes based on a filter first and then apply different schemas for parsing a column with a json string.